# Exporting to a CSV File in Java

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to export data using CSV. I am not an advanced coder so it would be nice to keep that in mind while helping ;)

I am very confused on why it is denying my access and have not much of an idea on how to fix it.

```
package Testing;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Testing
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
       generateCsvFile("c:\\test.csv"); 
   }

   private static void generateCsvFile(String sFileName)
   { 
    try
    {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);

        writer.append("DisplayName");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("Age");
        writer.append('\n');

        writer.append("MKYONG");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("26");
            writer.append('\n');

        writer.append("YOUR NAME");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("29");
        writer.append('\n');

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    }
}
```

I am getting the fallowing error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\test.csv (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Testing.Testing.generateCsvFile(Testing.java:17)
at Testing.Testing.main(Testing.java:10)
```

Thanks to anyone that could help.

Comment: The user that you are using to run the program doesn't have access to the file. Are you using Windows Operating System ?

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows 8.

Comment: If you absolutely have to use this location to write files change read/write permissions on the C: for the user that you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This access denied message is from the Operating System to Java. So, the java program is not being allowed (by the Operating system) to access that file. This could be because of multiple reasons, including

- The user running the java program does not have access to `C:\`
- The user running the java program does not have access to `C:\test.csv`
- `test.csv` is being edited from another program.

I would start with writing the file to the current directory (from where the program is being run) or to user home (which is `C:\users\userName\AppData` on Win 7+). User home can be got programatically by `System.getProperty("user.home")`

Also, `C:\` exists only on Windows, so hardcoding this is not a very good idea. Use the `user.home` property or externalize the file location (get the file name from a properties file. This way you can change the location for different operating systems)

Answer (score 2):

You usually cannot write/create files in root `C:\` folder because of permission issues.

Though you can write/create files in your home directory at will. The following solution should work across operating systems.

```
generateCsvFile(System.getProperty("user.home") + "test.csv");
```

Yo can also write to your `temp` folder.

```
generateCsvFile(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "test.csv");
```

In the case of wanting to create a file in the Root directory, follow these instructions
http://www.mkyong.com/computer-tips/cant-create-file-in-the-c-drive-root-directory-windows-8/

Disclaimer, cannot test since I do not have Windows8.

Comment: I think you meant `user.home`

Comment: I did not downvote, but I don't think this answer is "wrong".

Comment: I have tried this just now, no error though nothing is in console.

Comment: Try adding a `/` character. to file path, `generateCsvFile(System.getProperty("user.home") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "test.csv");`

Comment: The answer is not wrong, but the answer suggest an alternate approach rather than fixing the root cause. Ideally if someone has to write in C:\, permissions need to fixed.

Comment: Updated my answer to accommodate writing to `C:\`